# How to create AR labels for ModelEntity in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, realitykit, reality-composer

I have a very simple app which puts down an `.rcproject` file.

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var marLent: Bool = false
    
    private lazy var arView: ARView = {
        let arview = ARView()
        arview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        arview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return arview
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()

        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
        
        configureUI()
        setupARView()
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        view.addSubview(arView)
        
        arView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            arView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            arView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            arView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            arView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    private func setupARView() {
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
}
```

How could I create a label for the placed down Entity which looks like something like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC5cE.jpg). So basically have a text that points on the entity and the text would be the entity's name for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to create info dots with text plates for AR scenes. Here's an animated `.gif`.

[image]

- the first way – using `Autodesk Maya 2024` with pre-installed USD plugin (it's the most preferable way, because you can apply both animation and Python scripting techniques);
- the second one – using `Reality Composer` (it's quite fast way, but you won't be able to exactly replicate info dots animation, like in Apple's `.reality` sample files);
- the third one – programmatically in `RealityKit`;
- the fourth way – programmatically using [Pythonic USD Schema](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-usdz-schemas-367ae40c6950).

Nonetheless, for brevity, let's see how we can do it in Reality Composer app.

[image]

### Reality Composer's behaviors

In Reality Composer's scene, drag and drop `.png` files with transparency (8-bit RGBA) to create an info dot and an info plate – each file will be turned into plane with its corresponding image. After that, you can apply Reality Composer's behaviors to any separate part of your model.

[image]

Create first custom behavior with a `Scene Start` trigger, then add `LookAtCamera` and `Hide` actions (when scene starts, both, a cylinder primitive and info plate must be hidden).

[image]
[image]

Create second behavior with a `Tap` trigger, then add `LookAtCamera`, `Show`, `Wait` and `Hide` actions (three actions must be merged together). If you tap an info dot, both hidden objects will be shown with the help of fade in/out animation.

[image]
[image]

Final step: save the scene as `.reality` file.

Hope, now you have an idea how it's done.