# How to author a Reality File?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

How do we author a Reality File like the ones under "Examples with animations" at https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/ ??

For example, "The Hab" : https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/hab/hab_en.reality

Tapping on various buttons in this experience triggers various complex animations. I don't see any way to accomplish this in Reality Composer.

And I don't see any way to export/compile to a "reality file" from within Xcode.

How can I use multiple animations within a single GLTF file?
How can I set up multiple "tap target" on a single object, where each one triggers a different action?

How do we author something similar? What tools do we use?

Answer (score 1):

#### It's possible!

You should create [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599901/how-to-use-multiple-animations-on-a-usdz-model-with-realitykit/76600896#76600896) of animations in Maya, save them as `.usdz` files, load those animations into Reality Composer 1.5, apply the desired [behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933508/how-to-create-ar-labels-for-modelentity-in-realitykit/74935039#74935039) to them, and export a scene as `.reality` file.

#### How to...

To switch one `.usdz` animation to another one with a simple tap, use the following approach.

[image]

Create two `.usdz` files with animated red sphere in Maya. First file must contain a sphere moving along +X axis, and a second file must contain the same sphere moving along +Y axis (with X axis offset). Not a single line of Swift code required.

In Reality Composer create 2 empty scenes and import first `.usdz` file into first scene, then second `.usdz` file – into second one. After that, apply the appropriate behaviors accordingly.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is this all within Reality Composer or does this require Xcode? How do I "load an animation" in RC? Thank you!

Comment: Reality Composer is a part of Xcode. I've updated my answer.